# how to navigate new user to different page when he logins for the first time using classic asp

Tags: session, authentication, asp-classic, vbscript, session-cookies

I'm using classic ASP ,where there is one single login form for admin and other users.
I was able to redirect admin and user to different pages as they login, but for new users I want them to go authentication page when he first logs in.
How do I go around with it. I'm not so good with sessions infact I used session variable to navigate User and employee to different pages. Is session going to play part in this too..??.

this is what I used to navigate user and admin to different pages

```
Session("Username")=request.form("user_name")
    if request.Form("sub_but") <> "" then
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='"&request.form("user_name")&"' AND Password='"&request.form("pwd")&"'"
    rs.open sql, con, 1, 2  
     if rs.EOF then

        response.Write("<script language='javascript'>{attention_emp();}</script>")
            else
       if(rs("UserName"))= "vppl-1" then
       response.Redirect ("admin.asp")
    else
          Response.Redirect ("leave.asp")
    end if 


    end if
    rs.close
    end if
```

Comment: Sessions can be used to store the authentication of a user. It is not clear from your question what the problem is. Does the script give you errors?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use session variables for this, use a simple cookie, if the cookie or the user don't exist then redirect them to the authentication form. Session variables are kept only for the time the browser is open, the next time they are gone.

But is this is on an IIS server just activate NTLM (Windows authentication) on the site and then you can control access and retrieve the user and even his access rights from it with a simple Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"); 
This is called single side logon, which means, once the user is logged in, he doesn't need to logon again, windows takes care of providing the authentication for you which means happy users 8>).
You simply give ntfs rights on the map containing the site and voila, you have your basic security.

Answer (score -1):

I would set a bool in your user_table which is by default false.
then you check in youre code if its false, if yes redirect to the authentication page and set the bool to true.

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2000 where boolean DATA TYPE is not present instead....bit DATA TYPE is available with value 0 and 1

Comment: Okay, then you use that one. You can set it to 0 by default and redirect the user to a different page, and when the user loads that page you set the 0 to a 1 in your database.

Comment: @WesleyLalieu: Doesn't this mean that a user will ALWAYS be authenticated, unless they explicitly logout?